# R dataframe - adding new column with starting date of year quarter

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

```
yq       store   value    
2014 Q1  1000    89
```

How can I add an extra column which contains, based on the year quarter in column 1 , the starting date of that quarter. So in this example I would like to add: 01-01-2014.

Answer (score 2):

For instance, you could use [`lubridate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html):

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(yq = "2014 Q1", store = 1e3, value = 89)

df_new <- df %>% 
    mutate(start_date = lubridate::yq(yq))
```

## Results

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  yq      store value start_date
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <date>    
1 2014 Q1  1000    89 2014-01-01
```

Comment: Or from `zoo` `as.Date(as.yearqtr(df$yq))`

Comment: @akrun I was thinking that as well, but running `as.Date` on `zoo::as.yearqtr(df$yq, format = "%Y Q%q")` returns an error

Comment: @Konrad It is already in the default format, so, you don't need to specify the format

Comment: @akrun Like that `zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearqtr(df$yq, format = "%Y Q%q"))` I was calling `as.Date` from wrong namespace :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is as in the Note at the end, first convert `yq` to a `yearqtr` object.  Such objects are represented internally as year + frac where frac = 0, 1/4, 2/4 and 3/4 for Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4. They render as shown below and can be readily manipulated, e.g. `yq + 1/4` is the next quarter.   See `?yearqtr` for more information.

Given the `yearqtr` object you may not even need the `Date` column; however, if you do then convert that to `Date` class.  The default conversion is to give the first of the quarter.  (Use the `frac=1` argument of `as.Date` to get the end of the quarter.)

```
library(zoo)
transform(transform(DF, yq = as.yearqtr(yq)), Date = as.Date(yq))
```

giving:

```
       yq store value       Date
1 2014 Q1  1000    89 2014-01-01
```

If you don't need `yq` as a `yearqtr` object then it could be shortened slightly:

```
transform(DF, Date = as.Date(as.yearqtr(yq)))
```

### Note

The input shown reproducibly is assumed to be:

```
DF <- structure(list(yq = structure(1L, .Label = "2014 Q1", class = "factor"), 
    store = 1000L, value = 89L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```